# Macro para Importação no Access

Tags: visual-basic-6, microsoft-access

Preciso de ajuda para criar uma macro de importação no Access, no caso utilizando VisualBasic, preciso fazer o download de um arquivo zip, dentro deste zip há uma planilha de excel, eu preciso extraí-la, copiar todos os dados, copiar e colar pra uma tabela, esse processo deve ser repetido mais duas vezes porém para outros links, arquivos e tabelas, podem ajudar?

Comment: Por favor posta o seu código e onde está encontrando dificuldades, para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: @davidterra eu fiz o módulo do zip, agora o do download e de importação eu não tenho a mínima ideia de como fazer

`Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim startPath As String = "d:\teste" 
        Dim zipPath As String = "d:\teste\teste.zip" 
        Dim extractPath As String = "c:\teste\extract"

        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath)

        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath)
    End Sub 

End Module`